# asp.net mvc and js - track if any changes when close

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation

i'm trying to show confirmation message when user leaves (or refreshes) the page.
But need this only when have unsaved changes

i use window.onbeforeunload.

but was unable to track wih jquery change() or live() methods.
I have latest Chrome and jquery 1.8.xx

As for controls, i have only inputs.

One with strong id 'idTruckTrailerTag'.

Rest are auto-generated with asp.net mvc 
like "Tasks_0__ActualDate", "Tasks_0__ActualTime".
Number inside grows and can have 2 or even 3 digits.

Can someone help me with really working example ?

```
function confirmExit()
{
    return "All changes made will be lost.";
}

$(document).submit(function(){
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    // page loaded fine
    var textbox = document.getElementById("idTruckTrailerTag");
    if (textbox != null)
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

    etc...


@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TruckTrailerTag, new { @id = "idTruckTrailerTag", @style = "height: 20px; min-height: 20px; border:1px solid #aaaaaa; color: #414040;" })

@{var loadActualDateValue = Model.Tasks[i].ActualDate.HasValue ? Model.Tasks[i].ActualDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : string.Empty;}
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tasks[i].ActualDate, new { @class = "actual-date", @Value = loadActualDateValue, @style = "height: 20px; min-height: 20px; border:1px solid #aaaaaa; color: #414040;" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tasks[i].ActualTime, new { @textInputType = "Time", @style = "width: 125px; height: 20px; min-height: 20px; border:1px solid #aaaaaa; color: #414040;" })
```

Comment: We need to see your control and HTML markup.

Comment: For now i added onchanged to all textboxes. so currently i dont use jquery